# Left join weirdness

Tags: sql, left-join

At least with MariaDB v10.x, why truth clauses with left joins doesn't work as I expect when there is `NULL` return value?

The below works:

```
SELECT
    u.id
FROM
    user u

    INNER JOIN role r on r.user = u.id
    INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id = r.customer
    LEFT JOIN customer_subclass cs ON cs.customer = c.id

WHERE
    u.status = 'NEW' AND (cs.code != 4 OR cs.code IS NULL)
```

but when I first tried

```
WHERE
    u.status = 'NEW' AND cs.code != 4
```

it didn't work when `cs.code` was `NULL`. Why do I have to specifically test against `NULL` itself? I would assume `NULL != 4`?

Comment: Move the cs.code != 4 to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that engine is build upon three-valued predicate logic. If predicate compares two non null values then it can be evaluated to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If at least one of then is `NULL` then predicate evaluates to third logical value - `UNKNOWN`.

Now what happens in `WHERE` clause? It is designed in such a way that it returns rows where predicate evaluates to `TRUE` only! If predicate evaluates to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN` then corresponding row is just filtered out from resultset.

At first this is very confusing and leads newcomers into world of `SQL` to several typical mistakes. They just don't think that data may contain `NULL`s. One of classic mistake is for example:

```
Employyes(Name varchar, Contry varchar) 
'John', 'USA'
'Peter', NULL
'Mike', 'England'
```

And you want all rows where `Contry` is not `USA`. And you just write:

```
select * from Employees where Country <> 'USA'
```

and get only:

```
'Mike', 'England'
```

as a result. This is very confusing at first glance, but as far as you understand that engine is doing three-valued logic the result is logical.

Answer (score 0):

Because comparing with `null` results in neither `true` nor `false`. It is **unknown**.

And that is true for all DB engines I know. The `is` operator handles especially `null` values which you already use.

Answer (score 0):

With the `LEFT JOIN`'s right side table's `cs.code != 4` condition in the `WHERE` clause, the `LEFT JOIN` executes as a regular `INNER JOIN`.

The solution is to move that condition to the `ON` clause, to get true `LEFT JOIN` behavior.

```
SELECT
    u.id
FROM
    user u

    INNER JOIN role r on r.user = u.id
    INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id = r.customer
    LEFT JOIN customer_subclass cs ON cs.customer = c.id AND cs.code != 4

WHERE
    u.status = 'NEW'
```